# How to create search filter for grid, in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

jQuery Mobile supports a search filter on list. I wonder if a similar search filter can be created for other UI components, such as grid. Anyone has any experience? Customization? How?

Comment: What grid component/library are you using?

Comment: The grid layout of jQuery Mobile. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/#/demos/1.1.0/docs/content/content-grids.html